# discord.py get a server prefix from .json file

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I just got into coding discord bots using discord.py (Python 3.8; discord.py 1.5.1) and I ran into a problem. I want to give the user the server prefix when he/she uses my custom help command (which just returns a string with all commands and the prefix). I have stored the prefixes of servers in a .json file, but how can I return the server prefix from that file?

Tell me if you need some parts of my code to be able to find a solution.

Comment: Can you upload a code snippet of your json file?

Comment: ```{

    "781524858026590218": "k-"

}```

Is this what you want?

Comment: I've submitted an answer, let me know if that's what you wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is your `prefixes.json` file:

```
{
    "781524858026590218": "k-"
}
```

You can grab the ID of the guild and have it check the json file for that prefix:

```
import json

@client.command()
async def GetPrefix(ctx):
    with open("prefixes.json", "r") as f:
        data = json.loads(f.read())
        guildID = str(ctx.guild.id)
        prefix = data[guildID]
        await ctx.send("Prefix:", prefix)
```

Comment: I used the code in a cog, but it doesn't work anymore for some reason
`@commands.command()
    async def ping(self, ctx):
        with open("./prefixes.json", "r") as f:
            data = json.loads(f.read())
            guildID = str(ctx.guild.id)
            prefix = data[guildID]
        await ctx.send(f"pong; {round(self.client.latency * 1000)}ms")
        print(f"{ctx.message.author} triggered '{prefix}ping'")`

Comment: Sorry, it's a bit hard to read, but I don't know how to fix that

Comment: also, you can simply use `ctx.prefix` for that, a lot easier.

Comment: I didn't get any error, I just don't get a message on discord from the bot anymore when I trigger the command

Comment: You'll need to post another question for that.